# Handling multiple accounts with the same email AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I'm currently integrating the google sign in into my app, and just found out that cognito does not automatically see the user with the same email, logged through a social provider, as the same user that has already registered with the same email with cognito

Now this poses a problem on how is the best way do deal with it. The problem here is that each cognito user has a different sub ID, and my Dynamo database identifies the users with the PK USER#{subID}. This means that a user logging in with a social provider will not find his original account data, but it will look like a new account

I saw that Cognito offers the possibility to merge accounts but I also saw that it's quite tricky and has a few issues that I think ruin the user experience.

My first thought was to leave the cognito identities as separate and create a simple PK-SK object on dynamo, having the USER#{providerSubID} - SK#ORIGINAL#{ogSubID}. This way I'll "only" need to spend 2 RCUs to retrieve the real user information.

Is it overkill to create a dynamo object just for mapping?
Is there any documented "best practice" to handle this type of situation, without merging the accounts in cognito?